# Sorting associative arrays in Python

Tags: python

How can an associative array be sorted by key in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)?

I have the following structure:

```
people = [
    {'name' : 'Bob', 'number' : '123'},
    {'name' : 'Bill', 'number' : '234'},
    {'name' : 'Dave', 'number' : '567'},
]
```

I want to sort by name. Is there a built in function to do this?

Comment: Did you google "Sorting associative arrays in python"?  What was wrong with the documentation you found on sorting associate arrays?

Comment: googling the title of this question...brings you right back to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `sorted` function's `key` parameter:

```
sorted(people, key=lambda dct: dct['name'])
```

There is an [excellent Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html) which explains how this works.

---

```
>>> people = [
    {'name' : 'Bob', 'number' : '123'},
    {'name' : 'Bill', 'number' : '234'},
    {'name' : 'Dave', 'number' : '567'},
]       
>>> sorted(people, key=lambda dct: dct['name'])
[{'name': 'Bill', 'number': '234'}, 
 {'name': 'Bob', 'number': '123'}, 
 {'name': 'Dave', 'number': '567'}]
```

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
import operator
sorted(people, key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
```

Using `operator.itemgetter('name')` is slightly faster than using 
`lambda dct: dct['name']`.